# How to make erlang look for module within sub-directories of current directory?

Tags: erlang

I'm a newbie to Erlang just having gone through some tutorials on Erlang. Coming from TDD back-ground I thought I should follow some TDD principles in Erlang. I have organized my code as below

```
root
|- tests
|   |- name_builder_tests.erl
|- src
|   |- name_builder.erl
```

I start Erlang shell in `root` directory. But I cannot compile my `erl` files from there so I have to switch to `tests` or `src` directories every time I make a change to one of those files and I need to compile them.

Is there any way I can tell shell to look for module in all the sub-directories when compiling modules or executing functions from particular modules? What I'm trying to ask is, if my shell is at `root` directory can I successfully execute following

```
c(name_builder).
c(name_builder_tests).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let organize code like this.

```
root
|- test
|   |- name_builder_tests.erl
|- src
|   |- name_builder.erl
|- rebar
|- rebar.config
```

Than run './rebar compile eunit'.
Rebar script and docs you can find here https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki

Comment: After a lot of ado about separating test code from production code, I gave up. Going with rebar. It is pretty elegant.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches when doing unit testing, is to place the tests within the same module as the production code:

```
-module(my_code).
-export([run/0]).

run() -> ok.

-ifdef(TEST).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

run_test() ->
    ?assertEqual(ok, run()).

-endif.
```

That way you have the tests close to you.
Regarding the availability of the code, you should run the erlang shell using the "-pa" parameter and specify the location of your code:

```
erl -pa src/
```

that's because you're compiling by default will put the beam files to the same folder as the sources.
But I would recommend using something like rebar, as it will make your life easier.

HTH,
Alin

Comment: I read of the approach to "put code and tests in one module" but to be honest, I do not like that approach. Mixing tests with production code is a bad idea I guess. What is rebar by the way?

Comment: The advice of using rebar is basically just a way of giving the advice to build your application using the [standard OTP structure](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-otp-applications). [Rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar) is merely a tool that can help with that.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that mixing tests with production code is saner/safer with functional programming languages. You don't have to worry about global variables or private object methods.

Comment: @macintux After some reading around ability compiling the code with tests included/excluded I get your point that in Erlang world, it is acceptable to have tests and production code sit in same file. But for my OO mind, it still feels little unclean.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an [Emakefile](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html#files-2) as well to tell the compiler where to look for source files.

Create a file named Emakefile in the root dir with following contents

```
{'src/*', [debug_info,
   {i, "src"},
   {i, "include"},     
   {outdir, "ebin"}]}.
{'test/*', [debug_info,
    {i, "src"},
    {i, "include"},
    {i, "test"},        
    {outdir, "ebin"}]}.
```

Now compile all modules using `erl -make` which will put all `.beam` files inside the `ebin/` dir.

Then start the shell by running the command `erl -pa ebin/` which will add the ebin dir to sys path

PS 1: I am pretty much an erlang newbie too and I learnt this approach from [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com), more precisely from [this lesson](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/designing-a-concurrent-application#lay-them-foundations)

PS 2: If you are working on an app that is planned to be more complicated than this, I would recommend you to check [rebar](https://github.com/rebar/rebar)

Comment: Going ahead with rebar but I like the `Emakefile` appraoch